# Need to show featured service boxes on my company website

Tags: plugins

I want something like this:

[image]

But I am not a native English speaker so I really couldn't find anyhing on google. Could somebody please spare me some time and let me know some phrases that would possibly lead me to any plugin that enables me to add something like shown in the attached picture?

Comment: But you perfectly asked in **English** what you really want!

Comment: @ArsalanMithani sure, but I needed 150(ish) words to explain what I need. How do I explain that to Google?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is something what you are looking for [Service Boxes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/service-boxes-widgets-text-icon/screenshots/)

You can search for Icons with text / featured services Plugins

You can [see this also](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-feature-boxes-with-icons-in-wordpress/)